# Lattice structures of two and 3 atoms basis

Tags: solid-state-physics

I seem to be having a real issue in how people instinctively know how to draw a unit cell lattice structure for 2 and 3 atom basis from vector points given.

So two typical example that I have been trying to do is sodium chloride and fluorite.

When I looked up the lattice points structure for the two compunds each was given like so.

Sodium Chloride $$Cl=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\:Na=\begin{pmatrix}0.5\\ 0.5\\ 0.5\end{pmatrix}$$

Fluorite

$$Ca^{2+}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\:F^-=\begin{pmatrix}0.25\\ 0.25\\ 0.25\end{pmatrix},\:F^-=\begin{pmatrix}0.75\\ \:0.75\\ \:0.75\end{pmatrix}$$

From wiki and the links I got the information from

> http://www.ilpi.com/inorganic/structures/nacl/index.html
>
> http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/chemistry/3_7/3_7_7.html

They are both FCC structure, what I cant seem to do however is draw what these cells look like from this information, now I have seen on google what these structure look like but if I was given this as a question to draw the cells from just these postions vectors, I am not sure I could. When I have seen these structures in google I cant see how the resemble FCC structures, I assume that there like a sub FCC between the lattice points but I honestly cannot see it.

Comment: I don't think 'instinct' has much to do with it - it is wholly a learned response (well, except perhaps for Wigner). But, you have been told it is an fcc lattice. So, draw a conventional fcc unit cell. The Cl (or Ca) at (0,0,0) are now the conventional fcc lattice points. Now add the Na (or F) relative to those Cl (or Ca). Done.

Comment: but that what I dont understand when it relative to those, reason being is that. (0,0,0) would be a single point on the lattice and (0.5,0.5,0.5) would be another single point how dose one draw from that. (0.5,0.5,0.5) is the middle of the cell to me not the face, how it constructed confuse me greatly.

Comment: Because they assume the conventional unit cell. The Na is at (0,0,0) and the other corners and face centers of the conventional unit cell. Using that coordinate system, the Cl is at half-way up the body diagonal. By symmetry, all the other Na ions have a Cl offset by (0.5,0.5,0.5) from them.

Answer (score 3):

Face centered cubic refers to the Bravais lattice not to the atom positions. The lattice has FCC symmetry. Your base (motif) for the lattice for NaCl has two atoms one Cl and one Na such that the distance between the two is a/2. It is convenient to put one of the two atoms in the motif at the points in the lattice. For instance Cl at $(0,0,0)$ and Na at (0, 0.5, 0), or any other choice. Once you draw the first motif (two atoms for NaCl) you then repeat this motif according to the FCC lattice symmetry in order to get the entire crystal.

[image: NaCl FCC unit cell]

There is a second layer of complexity when it comes to unit cell that have more than one motif like FCC. People like to reduce it to an even smaller, primitive cell and then give atom positions in that smaller cell. That is how you end up with information for only one pair of atoms, these are the atoms in the primitive cell. Na is now in the middle of this red cell.

[image: FCC primitive unit cell]

Comment: How do we find if a particular lattice point lie in primitive unit cell or not?For example basis for NaCl is Na at (0,0,0) and Cl at (1/2,1/2,1/2) as is clearly visible from diagram. But what about other crystals like diamond?How do we write basis for primitive unit cell in those crystals?

Comment: You just look it up. There are very riguros rules for lattice point positions. The Bible for this is the international tables for crystallography. Reading the tables required some training, so if you're not there yet there are various websites that store crystallographic information databases (https://www.iucr.org/resources/data/databases)

Comment: Okay... Well i am a beginner in solid state physics and i am reading solid state physics by Steven Simons and in a few exercises it is asked to write basis for the crystal but i just can't find a way to do that.